# mouseenter and mouseleave not triggered when hovering a mat-label

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can't capture the (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) events when hovering a mat-filed-set label (mat-label).

I need to show some contextual help information at the bottom of the screen when users hover certain form field label.

```
 <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
         <!-- this does not work -->
         <mat-label class="mat-h1"  
            (mouseenter)="mouseHovering($event)" 
            (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()">Background information
          </mat-label>

         <!-- this works -->
         <mat-icon class="md-18" mat-button 
            (mouseenter)="mouseHovering($event") 
            (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()" color="primary">info
         </mat-icon>
          :
          :
          some control
          :
 </mat-form-field>
```

```
// These methods are never triggered (when hovering the mat-label)
  mouseHovering($event) {
    :
    //(logic to display a bottom sheet)
  }

  mouseLeave() {
    :
    //(logic to display a bottom sheet)
  }
```

Able to trap events the same way it's possible without using a mat-label

Comment: Please, post a sample in StackBlitz so we can see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason is because angular has `pointer-events: none` style on the mat-label component. They do this so that when the label isn't in the floating state, users see the correct cursor mouse icon on input hover.  you can enable pointer events easily with css:

```
mat-label.has-events {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

<mat-label class="has-events">
```

or inline:

```
<mat-label style="pointer-events:auto;">
```

this should be fine as you are in 'always' float setting, but this will cause your inputs to show the wrong cursor on hover if they are not in the float state.  you could probably work around this shortcoming though by setting the correct cursor on the element like `cursor: text` in css as well.

css like this could fix it so that point events fire only in the float state but also keeps the default cursor:

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-should-float mat-label.has-events {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: default;
}
```

demo here of this behavior and css options: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klmnau?file=app/form-field-label-example.html